# Remove files in subdirectories older than 1 day with Linux command

Tags: linux, bash, rm

I am honestly nowhere near to be a decent bash scripter, but I made a little research and found a command that seems to be useful

```
find /path/to/files* -mtime +1 -exec rm {} \;
```

The question is if this line will remove directories? Because I want to only remove files that are images (actually in a *.jpeg format)

Comment: you could `man rm`. rm does NOT remove directories, unless you're running it in recursive (`-r`) mode. you have to use `rmdir` to remove directories.

Comment: This will add filters to make sure it only matches files than end with `.jpg`: `find /path/to/files -name '*.jpg' -type f -mtime +1 -delete`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, `rm` without the `-r` flag does not remove directories.

It looks like you want to add some more filters:

- `-type f` to match only files
- `-name '*.jpeg'` to match only files ending with `.jpeg`

Lastly, instead of `-exec rm {} \;`, you could use the much simpler `-delete`.

Putting it together, this looks more appropriate for you:

```
find /path/to/files* -mtime +1 -type f -name '*.jpeg' -delete
```

Answer (score 1):

Then narrow your search results to *.jpeg files:

```
find /path/to/files* -mtime +1 -type f -name "*.jpeg" -exec rm {} \;
```

It's always better to remove the exec parameter to do a dry run before delete:

```
find /path/to/files* -mtime +1 -type f -name "*.jpeg"
```

Each line will be passed to rm command, and nothing more.